# convert original values in datatable to dummy values during database restore

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to change the original values in datatable to dummy values during restoring database. Is it possible to do?

I want a Script that can loop through all tables and their columns in the database and insert dummy data based on column type and size.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change your data **during** the database restore. As I know SQL Server restore databases as binary files (not SQL statements).

But you can change them **after** the restoring complete.

On the other side, why do you restore database if you are going to overwrite all the data ? May be it will be simpler to create empty database with your table structure and generate default (random, dummy) data ?

Comment: can able to execute trigger automatically after db restore?